# How to parse JSON with dynamic field names with Gson in Kotlin?

Tags: json, kotlin, annotations, gson, localdate

I have looked at a lot of articles but can't seem to figure out the answer. The problem being is that I get a json file like this from my api:

```
{
    "forecast": {
        "2020-01-04": {
            "date": "2020-01-04",
            "mintemp": 7,
            "maxtemp": 11,
            "avgtemp": 9,
            "hourly": 
             ...
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the "key" in this JSON is always the day of today (2020-01-04). The way I do this now is like this:

```
data class ForecastDaysContainer(
    @SerializedName("2020-01-04")
    var forecastday1: FutureWeatherEntry,
    @SerializedName("2020-01-05")
    val forecastday2: FutureWeatherEntry,
    @SerializedName("2020-01-06")
    val forecastday3: FutureWeatherEntry,
    @SerializedName("2020-01-07")
    val forecastday4: FutureWeatherEntry,
    @SerializedName("2020-01-08")
    val forecastday5: FutureWeatherEntry,
    @SerializedName("2020-01-09")
    val forecastday6: FutureWeatherEntry,
    @SerializedName("2020-01-10")
    val forecastday7: FutureWeatherEntry
)
```

This of course results in me changing the dates every day manually.

Is there any way I can set the `@SerializedName` to the date of today? When I try this with:

```
LocalDate.now().toString()
```

I get the error:

> An annotation argument must be a compile-time constant

I can't seem to find a decent fix for this in Kotlin.

Comment: Use can use map. Consider reading this article:http://findnerd.com/list/view/Parse-Json-Object-with-dynamic-keys-using-Gson-/24094/

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to have annotation data to be created dynamically. So you need to think it the other way around. With Gson you could try to implement custom `JsonDeserializer` that parses fields dynamically by that date value.

However I think that most convenient way would be to use `Map` as comment suggests. If you can make your `ForecastDaysContainer` like this:

```
data class ForecastDaysContainer(
    var forecast : Map<String, FutureWeatherEntry>
)
```

When deserialized you will then have a Map that contains possibly many days with the date as the key. So like:

```
val container = gson.fromJson(json, ForecastDaysContainer::class.java);
val forecast = container.forecast.get("2020-01-04");
```

Answer (score 1):

Gson has `parse()` method for that.

```
val key = "2020-01-04" // This is generated, probably?
val json = JsonParser().parse(jsonString)
val result = json.asJsonObject["forecast"].asJsonObject[key]
```